# Is there a way to get reach metric of facebook posts via webhook?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm getting the reach metrics via api call

```
{page-id}/fields=insights.metric(post_impressions){values}
```

But didn't find any way to get reach metric of facebook posts using webhook.

Do we get reach metrics using below endpoint

`$facebook_page_id.'/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=feed`

I'm following [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But didn't find any way to get reach metric of facebook posts using webhook.

There isn’t any.

The data you can get from this endpoint, is not data that would require any reaction “in real time” to begin with, so it would make rather little sense to integrate this into web hooks in the first place.

And these insight metrics get updated once a day only anyway, AFAIK.

Just make the API request, when you need the insights data.